# calculating 2 fields which are using IF statements and Aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

Being knocking my head on the wall on this one:

```
SELECT 
    vicidial_closer_log.CAMPAIGN_I,
    vicidial_closer_log.USER_GROUP,
    vicidial_closer_log.LEAD_ID,
    SUM(IF(PHONE_CODE = '1', 1,0)) AS 'Call_Count',
    SUM(IF(STATUS = 'DROP', 1, 0)) AS 'DROPS',
    SUM(IF(STATUS = 'AFTHRS',1,0)) AS 'After Hours'
FROM
    vicidial_closer_log
group by vicidial_closer_log.CAMPAIGN_I
;
```

I need to calculate a drop rate, basically dividing drops into call count. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the division:

```
SELECT vcl.CAMPAIGN_I, vcl.USER_GROUP, vcl.LEAD_ID,
       SUM(PHONE_CODE = '1') AS Call_Count,
       SUM(STATUS = 'DROP') AS DROPS,
       SUM(STATUS = 'AFTHRS') AS AfterHours,
       (SUM(STATUS = 'DROP') / NULLIF(SUM(PHONE_CODE = '1'), 0)) AS DropRate
FROM vicidial_closer_log vcl
GROUP BY vcl.CAMPAIGN_I;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases (`vcl`) make the query easier to write and to read.
- In MySQL, you don't need `if()` for counting; you can just use hte boolean expression.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Preferably, choose names that do not need to be escaped.  If they do, use backticks.
- You can handle divide-by-zero using `NULLIF()`.

Comment: We need to handle divide by zero condition as well.

Comment: Gordon, thank you sooo much, I am a newbie at this, you have helped me a great deal!